# unable to run commands in appiumstudio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

*I am trying to run scripts towards real devices and below are the steps which I followed for the same :*

1. I installed appiumstudio in my windows machine
2. Created some sample script using NATIVE_APP
3. I tried running the script towards android and iOS
4. For Android it works fine, but for ios it gives element not found
   issue
5. I am able spy all the native elements and tried adding adding the
   command from spy window, the command looks as below [appium
   script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiMVV.jpg), but when I run the same command it fails
6. I am able to spy the objects and add them to the script but why does
   the script fail when I try to run the same command from appiumstudio

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue some how. But I have not got any solution. When I use appiumstudio spy I am able to identify all required objects clearly, but when I tried retrieving the objects from page source during execution these objects are not available       
don’t know why this is happening

Comment: I guess XCUIElementType is something that is swipeable.
Try using the command "FindElement and Swipe"